# using std::sort() on a list<int>

Tags: file, sorting, linked-list, ifstream

How do you sort a list using the std::sort() function? I have tried the code below.

```
std::sort(listStorage.begin(), listStorage.end());
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That looks fine to me, can we see the definition of listStorage, the initial values and the output? If listStorage is not a primitive data type, you will need to pass a comparison functor as the third argument.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that you specified what listStorage is in the title. Never mind, check out jwd's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using:

```
listStorage.sort();
```

A linked list does not provide a random-access iterator, which is why std::sort won't work.